# Does every force which seems to have no effect cause a deformation?

Tags: forces

The example in our discussion was: If I glue a peanut to the ceiling, does the ceiling bend?

Some people argued that it wouldn't because ceilings do not bend for peanuts.

Some people argued that the force of gravity that pulls down the peanut would need an opposing force for the peanut to stay up and so the ceiling would have to bend.

So what actually happens?

Comment: There are no forces which have no effect. The definition of force is by effect i.e. acceleration. If there is no effect, then there is also no net force. It's a little more complicated to discuss why in a gravitating environment that acceleration is present, even when nothing seems to move (except for deformation).